# How to hide/remove all dialogue buttons from dialog window

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I'm using ModernUI for WPF (MUI) available on codeplex. It's a nice framework and I have no issues using it as a container for my pages.

I have added a Custom Dialog window but I do not want to use any of the default buttons.

In the init method I have commented out this line:

```
this.Buttons = new Button[] { this.OkButton, this.CancelButton };
```

But, a Close button appears instead?

Any ideas?

Thanks